# Is "Fix geometries" in QGIS working properly?

Tags: qgis, invalid-data, geometries

I am currently using QGIS 3.10 for my GIS project.

I run first “Check Validity” to see if there were any invalid features, then I used “Fix geometries” to correct them. Surprisingly, after running the tool, some records disappear. They are not the ones that had invalid geometries, apparently there was no error associated to them.

I tried also `v.clear` in GRASS but the output is the same.

In the attachment there is a screenshot. In green there are the records that are excluded, consequently in purple there is the output of the fix geometries operation.

What is happening?

I would like to add that:

That layer was created by merging three different layers. The original RS was `3003`, then I worked with `32633`. If I try to select a green feature with "identify feature", it does not work. I can only select it in the attribute table.

The WKT for the biggest area is:

```
MultiPolygon (((-70022.93775235500652343 4356612.83903689030557871, -70033.44437383068725467 4356676.23373439628630877, -70058.07100084889680147 4356799.64237685594707727, -70067.81066365703009069 4356879.73767098970711231, -70079.89986682194285095 4356944.62834090087562799, -70094.13052648061420768 4357051.93655685894191265, -70097.11876192037016153 4357118.7491516238078475, -70108.47082455002237111 4357175.90316490270197392, -70114.09759141085669398 4357241.62044944614171982, -70128.17780060053337365 4357296.40464758966118097, -70145.72314232040662318 4357356.55574035085737705, -70163.13857614283915609 4357382.11560796573758125, -70187.57393556577153504 4357417.13472822587937117, -70194.45490942639298737 4357465.00880192499607801, -70198.96601630817167461 4357510.15463916305452585, -70208.50567415030673146 4357574.86630669329315424, -70222.40646059555001557 4357632.19967091828584671, -70220.29612216958776116 4357698.65397778805345297, -70225.45438139047473669 4357752.81109483819454908, -70237.65252709644846618 4357834.36040506791323423, -70248.53602899669203907 4357879.95432206150144339, -70253.87338074727449566 4357931.56242744345217943, -70261.22208977327682078 4357990.99688531644642353, -70275.85944414278492332 4358056.0670990226790309, -70272.47422293422278017 4358122.4318254804238677, -70267.61524646449834108 4358173.32306734472513199, -70264.49876495462376624 4358235.8642183830961585, -70267.32669410004746169 4358323.15894734486937523, -70265.55431925563607365 4358366.58227643650025129, -70265.76333399198483676 4358472.90520782489329576, -70283.5069097502855584 4358548.44053405057638884, -70301.19083862705156207 4358570.1771442536264658, -70333.90016926894895732 4358596.81275278329849243, -70376.33773469924926758 4358612.60501783434301615, -70430.14870051061734557 4358647.90411178767681122, -70509.88360942353028804 4358698.84499100223183632, -70601.06174132728483528 4358750.08533595968037844, -70687.0522131557809189 4358802.24183788523077965, -70759.91916239575948566 4358840.66731253731995821, -70812.93143299769144505 4358870.01170057244598866, -70877.05600260861683637 4358905.26086743362247944, -70909.76545702666044235 4358931.89681295771151781, -70927.35979398840572685 4358954.90821402240544558, -70912.28421998012345284 4358987.14976060669869184, -70903.63138318818528205 4358982.69878847524523735, -70911.61729612888302654 4358960.20536413043737411, -70807.31536532449536026 4358895.23341137729585171, -70791.77193282113876194 4358915.91453592665493488, -70801.52004141348879784 4358923.00417706649750471, -70787.07188105047680438 4358946.32397708762437105, -70750.27002381696365774 4358923.24277883302420378, -70762.16911312262527645 4358899.74373663775622845, -70773.5502456147223711 4358901.8248838372528553, -70787.72951861878391355 4358882.32866526860743761, -70418.17291486880276352 4358667.79204825777560472, -70348.40771733538713306 4358627.29180370271205902, -70327.20879444654565305 4358637.32859129644930363, -70306.1891134021570906 4358644.81633027456700802, -70288.8137621326604858 4358655.12196561601012945, -70268.08279267733450979 4358676.71904323808848858, -70247.71030443382915109 4358693.21802832093089819, -70227.06895666336640716 4358713.54056493099778891, -70203.69932753650937229 4358736.23288743197917938, -70185.42777567368466407 4358759.28368181921541691, -70156.15347628074232489 4358793.08816096559166908, -70140.43095630733296275 4358816.31817258987575769, -70121.08392557955812663 4358854.66314639709889889, -70110.36984325898811221 4358879.52614457067102194, -70097.0368824420729652 4358923.41727581899613142, -70090.88310528278816491 4358956.28585809469223022, -70083.25577664689626545 4358973.68097914382815361, -70064.62568442884366959 4359001.82974938210099936, -70053.82193738291971385 4359027.96722674556076527, -70053.30394182587042451 4359053.54718617722392082, -70060.41328686068300158 4359061.73204130958765745, -70079.9791709166020155 4359056.70384540781378746, -70098.71867145865689963 4359045.21343467943370342, -70114.90913880302105099 4359033.54376700706779957, -70127.90343129669781774 4359012.68359258957207203, -70141.54486392938997597 4359000.83466346468776464, -70155.38531533756759018 4359004.36957688629627228, -70161.13053146284073591 4359013.73933166172355413, -70167.43326064269058406 4359033.39486252330243587, -70177.91804513882379979 4359048.22119848430156708, -70186.59055243711918592 4359070.60502617433667183, -70187.34706041135359555 4359096.27465479634702206, -70179.45081042393576354 4359117.49333956465125084, -70205.74783113517332822 4359107.81520789675414562, -70209.94963834260124713 4359120.91890722420066595, -70192.75350043550133705 4359128.67538698203861713, -70218.59168478392530233 4359198.37596154119819403, -70253.54148095054551959 4359193.14881018828600645, -70432.87510765076149255 4359611.78193764295428991, -70251.56535517668817192 4359549.07859476655721664, -70230.07779824885074049 4359545.00577802490442991, -70217.89005586435087025 4359554.39522112254053354, -70216.81444482295773923 4359569.68944567535072565, -70226.38315339689143002 4359579.32815228682011366, -70248.04997700173407793 4359580.85194036830216646, -70263.90165030059870332 4359592.21334659866988659, -70289.94948352430947125 4359604.29183693137019873, -70317.2718444763449952 4359616.45997131150215864, -70357.33941987040452659 4359629.52446890808641911, -70406.32866523030679673 4359643.21643026452511549, -70444.85285199910867959 4359660.01488809194415808, -70468.34423901862464845 4359690.21797235962003469, -70456.38399640109855682 4359727.29343902692198753, -70605.79907500720582902 4359785.86714309267699718, -70621.26804799935780466 4359743.89660164061933756, -70636.52912673412356526 4359702.49005082529038191, -70675.42397835082374513 4359568.64107795339077711, -70687.98997133353259414 4359572.08648037072271109, -70651.82384857593569905 4359703.60607514157891273, -70636.65518661658279598 4359750.88019231986254454, -70626.52407053369097412 4359782.4544146005064249, -70724.80079126928467304 4359826.57397499401122332, -70823.61012912914156914 4359830.5629767058417201, -70843.15970124502200633 4359767.74423324316740036, -70876.08940873737446964 4359779.88264984171837568, -70808.5370750610018149 4360012.33499104902148247, -70823.97556737984996289 4360017.7832730058580637, -70930.88196125044487417 4359659.28874937724322081, -70882.42078684770967811 4359637.96314037591218948, -70966.25835510331671685 4359373.56718580238521099, -71020.44291550992056727 4359386.3271967452019453, -71075.38232459838036448 4359223.65891446731984615, -71071.35469922644551843 4359208.0063107768073678, -71082.53346005699131638 4359194.69925900921225548, -71094.54064403311349452 4359187.85462749842554331, -71118.46577048534527421 4359175.43999579269438982, -71143.75478363689035177 4359161.83996053505688906, -71177.8770226405467838 4359150.13925107475370169, -71196.72886366583406925 4359155.30180056393146515, -71199.30338224186562002 4359173.41445953957736492, -71191.20934055955149233 4359179.25219254475086927, -71174.01435014558956027 4359187.01450061239302158, -71152.81696468184236437 4359197.05834913440048695, -71126.07482013886328787 4359213.11840444710105658, -71102.44264171400573105 4359239.64326927252113819, -71094.19533886178396642 4359265.96441164892166853, -71082.71000778349116445 4359320.23829551972448826, -71070.90650935017038137 4359342.4677786435931921, -71055.75052367895841599 4359375.99048396572470665, -71046.22854493896011263 4359402.22234925720840693, -71033.26482136268168688 4359441.02206509280949831, -71024.48197425063699484 4359474.9909717096015811, -71016.32384939957410097 4359500.03742806427180767, -71007.15882700029760599 4359521.17072792258113623, -70995.1767853134078905 4359545.94942757487297058, -70990.84254353865981102 4359571.26361346337944269, -70996.43761853501200676 4359601.1156942518427968, -71011.7583706813165918 4359620.12081852648407221, -71038.372334053972736 4359642.47847060207277536, -71067.8925727749010548 4359659.91609784495085478, -71109.2415439342148602 4359673.0584514606744051, -71168.63907236861996353 4359702.83522531297057867, -71199.41781232238281518 4359727.67659691162407398, -71211.90948822186328471 4359768.51402818877249956, -71207.10908824601210654 4359810.45461960881948471, -71225.74576956976670772 4359832.82336829509586096, -71234.10421040467917919 4359888.71911269053816795, -71255.82983322208747268 4360022.63756600022315979, -71073.09658488712739199 4360202.75093290954828262, -70979.5902840121416375 4360164.48768427409231663, -70942.05836612184066325 4360247.44743186328560114, -71068.14767585834488273 4360277.19130145572125912, -71168.03090470400638878 4360379.96249089203774929, -71224.722326505696401 4360490.54802634287625551, -71171.58919830364175141 4360487.01548528391867876, -71206.3398288352182135 4360767.03264633938670158, -70252.95701031980570406 4361301.79344011843204498, -69976.02131682110484689 4361454.27639180608093739, -69747.93421091057825834 4361513.87750696949660778, -69526.92871529271360487 4361467.14494065009057522, -69269.07831847027409822 4361332.49934268929064274, -69149.35615692171268165 4361207.04930548742413521, -69051.57531924697104841 4360912.16287505719810724, -68999.1152994220610708 4360577.55901574343442917, -68974.9796608880860731 4360138.03537450172007084, -68987.68006352242082357 4359786.40347336046397686, -69000.40392755030188709 4359594.99320737458765507, -68787.89750438439659774 4359580.86727226991206408, -68812.66341465583536774 4359368.88725673872977495, -68981.25231822952628136 4359401.46412455197423697, -68940.14713122218381613 4359217.15124356094747782, -68688.62890290829818696 4358826.59809786546975374, -68466.86398888961412013 4358470.07066390570253134, -68391.76178538566455245 4358315.54603230208158493, -68339.31911671406123787 4358141.16707737743854523, -68187.69022697547916323 4357853.38507992960512638, -67994.98078137449920177 4357541.51419893279671669, -68067.88590168161317706 4357247.29307846259325743, -68224.41312583209946752 4357140.20588883571326733, -68295.93434098409488797 4357027.47044586855918169, -68221.52621851407457143 4356862.30856806505471468, -68166.9298824779689312 4356559.61564601492136717, -68118.72175247932318598 4356321.4387689521536231, -68165.4311643288237974 4356100.24257906619459391, -68274.54179337259847671 4356224.97793071903288364, -68944.08168908709194511 4357230.74328808952122927, -69087.86243691632989794 4357154.85388178005814552, -69191.99703897791914642 4357193.80877500120550394, -69268.49496234906837344 4357166.85545796062797308, -69347.10343317943625152 4357107.98613606672734022, -69376.13199040398467332 4356992.42578717879951, -70022.93775235477369279 4356612.83903689030557871)))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide, for example, the WKT of a small green polygon, and its coordinate system ?

Answer (score 4):

The polygons aren't valid because of the non-equality between the first and last vertices.

In your example :

1. `-70022.93775235`**500652343** `4356612.83903689030557871`
2. `-70022.93775235`**477369279** `4356612.83903689030557871`

So to correct that, and because the precision is too much for GIS data, I propose to change both of them into :

- `-70022.93775235 4356612.83903689030557871`

Comment: I cannot understand one point: why running the "check validity" tool, I don't get an error for such polygon?

Comment: @Geo_it: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯, maybe they aren't polygons in the first place ...

Comment: I took it for granted, as they seemed polygons. Is there a way to understand if all the records in my layers are polygons?